# Glide 4.11.0 load gif link not work with size small

Tags: android, android-glide

When i use glide load gif this work ok, but with gif size small below : "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50013823608_c85e0f97d2_o.gif", not work.

```
  Glide.with(ivThumbImg.getContext())
                            .load(imageTableModel.getLinkThumb())
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                            .into(new DrawableImageViewTarget(ivThumbImg));
```

or

```
   Glide.with(ivThumbImg.getContext())
                            .load(imageTableModel.getLinkThumb())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                            .into(ivThumbImg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by fixing the gif with a faster start time of a new image in the frame